# Unexpected behavior with PriorityQueue remove: Why isn't compareTo used?

Tags: java, equals, priority-queue, compareto

I am trying to use the priority queue, but the remove() is not working: 
My code:

```
PriorityQueue<OwnClass> pq=new PriorityQueue<OwnClass>();
OwnClass a=new OwnClass(1);
OwnClass b=new OwnClass(2);
OwnClass c=new OwnClass(3);
pq.add(a);
pq.add(b);
pq.add(c);
System.out.println("head:"+pq.peek());
pq.remove(new OwnClass(1));
System.out.println(pq.peek());
```

And the class implementation:

```
class OwnClass implements Comparable{

    int x;

    public OwnClass(int x){
        this.x=x;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {

        OwnClass a=(OwnClass) arg0;
        if(a.x>this.x)
            return -1;
        if(a.x<x)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return ""+x;        
    }
}
```

I think the output final output should be 2, since I am removing the added '1'. The compareTo() should be used by priority queue remove() but his does not seem to be the case. What I am doing wrong? I know pq.remove(a) will work, but then my code should also work

Comment: You haven't overridden the `equals` method; perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: but shouldnt the compareTo() method be enough?, as it can be used to check equals

Comment: It can and should be used, and by contract when  you write a Comparable class, you have to make it so that when compareTo() == 0 then equals() == true. However, a class can violate this contract, normally by accident. In this case OwnClass is violating the contract by not overriding equals; just check what new OwnClass(1).equals(new OwnClass(1)) returns (though compareTo will return 0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`remove()` will not use `compareTo()`, rather it will use `equals()` to find the object to remove. You need to override `equals()` on your class as well.

Edit: [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) for `PriorityQueue` (Thanks, @templatetypedef)

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#remove(java.lang.Object) for more details

Comment: ok, i understand, but wy is it implemented in this manner? it does not make sense to code two methods whne only one was enough

Comment: `remove(Object)` takes an `Object` - it does NOT have to be the same (generic) type of the `PriorityQueue`. Therefore, it cannot be forced into the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: I assume the reason it is implemented in this manner is because priority queues can hold multiple, unequal elements that have the same priority. The Priority Queue javadoc states "If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily"

Answer (score 2):

The `PriorityQueue` class's `remove` method has the following description:

> Removes a single instance of the specified element from this queue, if it is present. **More formally, removes an element e such that `o.equals(e)`, if this queue contains one or more such elements.** Returns true if and only if this queue contained the specified element (or equivalently, if this queue changed as a result of the call).

Thus `compareTo` is not used when determining whether to `remove` something.  I believe that this is because `PriorityQueue` implements `Collection`, and the behavior of `remove` must therefore be consistent with the behavior specified in `Collection`, which is

> Removes a single instance of the specified element from this collection, if it is present (optional operation). **More formally, removes an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)), if this collection contains one or more such elements.**

In other words, I believe this design decision is motivated by trying to fit `PriorityQueue` into the `Collection` framework, even though it is a bit odd.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Please note that PriorityQueue has an other constructor that takes a Comparator.
So it could be to keep the remove behavior consistent even if a Comparator is used or the objects in the priorityQueue implement the Comparable Interface, equals does not depend on any comparison except the base equals property of the Object.